# Cannot read html input field value using form.value - angular5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

I am using angular 5

In my html I generate the value of a input field using

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="unitCost" name="unitCost"    [(ngModel)]="unitCost" placeholder="Average Unit Price">
document.getElementById("unitCost").value = avgVal;
```

then I want to retrieve that generated value in my component.ts using

```
this.unitCost = form2.value.unitCost;
```

But it returns null value. instead if I type any value in the text field it works fine and returns the value I typed. Can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you use the `FormControl` in your  `.ts` file ?

Comment: Please don't use same word for id, name and model. Answer to your question is, this.unitCost will itself have value, because ngModel contains value and it's two way binding.

Comment: Don't mix Jquery with Angular and as a matter of fact you are already using 2 way data binding  `[(ngModel)]="unitCost"` does not it take care of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to achieve what you want is

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="unitCost"  [(ngModel)]="unitCost" placeholder="Average Unit Price">
```

now in your component class you will have a variable called unitCost and you can get or set the value of the text field like this

setting value - unitCost = 'value'
gettingValue - unitCost

let me know if this is clear or i will create an example for you

Comment: I am sorry! I don't get it. can you explain it a bit

Comment: here is an example I created please look at the app.component.ts and app.component.html https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1epn4j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngValue]` directive of angular.